# Where can I find a list of well known COM object GUIDS

Tags: com, guid

I was trying to get some unit tests to work when I got an error similar to:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
>   CLSID {BA3D0120-E617-4F66-ADCA-585CC2FB86DB}
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154

The resolution was to install Blackberry Desktop manager, and it was simple to intuitively figure it out because the program I was debugging had to do with blackberries.

Obviously Googling for the GUID gives enough information to lead you in the right direction. However, I was wondering if there was any sort of website that acts as an unoficcial registry for COM object GUIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answer yourself: Google, there are just too many GUIDs (for CoClasses, Interfaces, Events, and what not) in the world to keep track of them.

Comment: Ironically, this question is now the top Google hit for `ba3d0120-e617-4f66-adca-585cc2fb86db`.

Comment: @JeffKelley lol, we should have the tag noindex for all the questions that contains the answer "use google"